# MonoTouch 4 Interface Builder Code generation Problem

Tags: c#, interface-builder, xamarin.ios

Since I upgraded my MonoTouch to version 4, I have problems with the *.xib.designer.cs files. MonoTouch don't include any usings to MonoTouch.UIKit. If i try to compile my application, it miss many classes form the UIKit namespace. If I add the usings, everything works fine. But the next time it regenerate the *.xib.designer.cs the usings are away again. I have many files that are build with the interface builder, adding them every time is a no go.

I use XCode 3.2.6 and MonoTouch 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Mono 2.10.1 from the MonoDevelop updater.

Comment: I read this on the MonoTouch page, I will look into it in the next days: "You MUST use the MonoTouch version of MonoDevelop from the above link, or the version from MonoDevelop's built-in updater, since it may contains fixes that are not in MonoDevelop 2.4." I downloaded the version suggested on the Mono page, that could be a problem. I will also try the 2.10.1 Mono version, thanks

Comment: As long as you have no outstanding updates in the MonoDevelop updater (Help->Check for Updates) you should be fine.

Comment: Reinstalling everything (MT, Mono and MD) fixed it.